# How many Uncles (Ommer) can be included and how is the reward distributed

Tags: blockchain, uncle-blocks, reward

how many uncles can one block include? I think I read somewhere that you can only include maximum 2 uncles, is that true?
If a block includes 2 uncles or more, how is the reward distributed between those?
If one uncle gets 7/8 of the static reward, the 7/8 is distributed between multiple uncles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One block can include up to two uncles. If a block references two uncles, each uncle will earn 7/8th of 5 ETH to whoever mined that uncle.  Each uncle being referenced will also earn a small reward per uncle (1/32 of 5 ETH) to the miner who references the uncles in his / her block.

You can find [more details here](https://bitsonblocks.net/2016/10/02/a-gentle-introduction-to-ethereum/) in the Rewards Mining section.